# How to rewrite [NSRunLoop runUntilDate:] to GCD code?

Tags: iphone, ios, grand-central-dispatch, nsrunloop

Just for my curiousity, I am trying to rewrite the following code

```
// show HUD (with animation)
[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"loading..."];

// wait for HUD to safely finish showing its animation
// (loading HUD will be visible for 1 sec)
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]]

// dismiss HUD
// (dismiss HUD will be visible for 2 sec)
[SVProgressHUD dismissWithSuccess:@"finished!" afterDelay:2];
```

into the code using Grand Central Dispatch.

I tried using dispatch_source_t, dispatch_semaphore_t, and dispatch_after, 
but doesn't quite work well:( and I need your help!

Please note that I don't want to wrap SVProgressHUD's methods with any blocks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really can't.   Or, you could, but it'd be a ton of work that would ultimately just wrap the `NSRunLoop` stuff itself.

Within the context of iOS and Mac OS X, the main event loop is a run loop and things like modal panels, HUDs, and the like are all designed around that detail.

The code you are showing is a *nested run loop*.  You are effectively running the main run loop in a sub-loop within an outer loop that is also maintained by the main run loop!   (If you were to set a breakpoint on an action method fired within your internal loop, you would see what I mean in the backtrace).

Comment: Do you mean, main-runloop nested in the same main-runloop??? It looks like I need to study more on run loop mechanism itself...

Comment: Yup. That is exactly what I mean!  This is all described (with pictures) in the docs.